# Can I use flows to write a screening interview page to be used as a public page

Tags: visualforce, flow

I need to write a visualforce page with a preset flow like interview or screening questions.
Can I use flows to write a screening interview page to be used as a public page?

Comment: You can surface a Salesforce Visual Flow in a Visualforce page and surface this eternally. With a Visual Flow there would need to be a running user that has permissions to update any objects from the responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that quite easily.  You'll need to make sure the Site Guest User and any other internal users have access to that page.  Its really simple to set up a Flow in Visualforce, take a look here: http://salesforcesidekick.com/2015/05/25/how-to-put-your-flow-in-a-visualforce-page/

After you do that, you just need to make sure the Site Guest User has the necessary access to CREATE the records you need them to create for their 'questions' to be stored in Salesforce.

If you run into 'issues with permissions', keep in mind, you can do any change in a custom object you want, and then have that custom object trigger a Process Builder and another Flow to finish your 'functionality' as Process Builder fired Flows run as SYSTEM!